# Cannot publish my InfoPath form in SharePoint 2007 any more

Tags: document-library, infopath

When I published my InfoPath form to my SharePoint 2007, it gives me the following error:

```
updating the content type failed
```

I went through a search and many of the search return ([Microsoft Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/6e4f5c0c-44ff-452e-abb1-c889107d9e88/), [Thor Project](http://thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2007/06/26/infopath-2007-publishing-to-sharepoint-updating-the-site-content-type-failed.aspx))  give me a this [link](http://acuffgroup.com/2009/01/21/tip-for-publishing-infopath-form-to-sharepoint-library/), which no longer available.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can publish my InfoPath form successfully? (fyi - it did publish successfully previously but after adding 8 new fields and promoting them, I got the above error)

**UPDATE**

Strange, I went back to my SharePoint library to perform a quick check and I notice that my SharePoint library has the 8 new fields being successfully published. So, why does the error message appear since it was successfully? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix for your problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958139/en-us .Also you can have a look at this article mentioned below.

http://doolbox.blogspot.in/2008/09/publishing-infopath-forms-updating.html